# CNN on not-images based dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conv-neural-network

I would like to test the performances of a CNN model applied on a dataframe of not-images data with 90 features. More particularly, these features are sampled every minute and I would like to pass to the CNN model the last 60 minutes of data; therefore the shape of each group of data will be (60, 90, 1), just one channel. The problem is on transforming this large dataframe (1 year) in a proper shape for the CNN model. All the examples I find refer to images so that they are already prepared in the right shape. How could I transform the original dataset into groups of (60, 90) sizes where 90 are the features and 60 the last 60 1-minute long ranges?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "60 the last 60 1-minute long ranges"?

Comment: It looks like that you want to give your data as a sliding windows of last 60 sample, right ? considering for example you have one year, means you have 24 * 60 * 365 X 90 sample. If you want to give the data as a sliding window , meaning samlpe 1 and sample 2 both have 59 data same and only one different , then create your Dataset class which in getitem returns the last 60 sample. otherwise it is a simple reshaping

Comment: exactly, having in mind that I have to feed a CNN model. So each row of teh original dataset reports the figures sampled in one minute. I wanna feed the CNN with the last 60 rows (60 minutes), each row having the figures of the 90 features. So the original dataset should be grouped somehow in sub-datasets having the last 60 rows (the 60-th one is the current one, the one to which are linked the current targets). Each of these groups is equivalent to the concept of "image", anyway a matrix of 2D data.

Comment: the number of groups are (24*60*365) each group shape is (60, 90), where 60 are the last 60 rows including the current one and 90 the features.